# Using SASS variables to generate inline CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, gruntjs

I'm wanting to know if you can use SASS variables to generate inline CSS.

I'm aware you can do the following:

```
$my-class: yellow;
$yellow: #ffff00;

.#{$my-class} {
    color: $yellow;
}
```

And then inline the CSS using a Grunt task which outputs:

```
<div class="yellow" style="color: #ffff000;">Hello world</div>
```

But is it possible to use a variable:

```
$font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
```

In such a way:

```
<div style="font-family: $font-family;">Hello world</div>
```

Which would output:

```
<div class="font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Hello world</div>
```

I'm pretty sure you can't with basic SASS but it would good to hear some thoughts on it.

Comment: you might be interested in an html preprocessor http://jade-lang.com/reference/conditionals/

Comment: That's similar to the Kit language: https://incident57.com/codekit/help.html#kit however I'd like to be able to control the whole process with SASS if at all possible.

Comment: Usually use inline CSS is not a very good thing. You can check this link http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm .

Maybe if you explain what you are trying to do becomes easier to help you.

Comment: @PedroMoreira It's mainly for email newsletters.

Comment: Short answer, you can't. especially if it's for newsletter consider to simplify your code procedure since you already be aware of the painful email structure

Comment: I made a quick research and you can share variables between SASS and javascript: http://viget.com/extend/sharing-data-between-sass-and-javascript-with-json . Maybe it helpes :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use CSS variables

```css
.box {
--difference: blue;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">1</div>
<div class="box" style="background: var(--difference)">2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a html preprocessor such as [jade](http://jadelang.net/) together with a tool like [sass-extract](https://github.com/jgranstrom/sass-extract) to accomplish this.

Here is an example where you would get the result in your example.

*style.scss*

```
$fontFamily: Arial;
```

*template.jade*

```
div(style="font-family: #{$fontFamily.value};") Hello world
```

*index.js (could also be a grunt/gulp task)*

```
const sassExtract = require('sass-extract');
const jade = require('jade');

const style = sassExtract.renderSync({ file: './style.scss' });
const html = jade.renderFile('./template.jade', style.vars.global);

console.log(html);
```

**Outputs**

```
<div style="font-family: Arial">Hello world</div>
```